# the entire body of an individual is unfamiliar at the conclusion of the procedure

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the phrase "the entire body of an individual is unfamiliar at the conclusion of the procedure" correct in English? What does it mean? Especially, what does "conclusion" mean here? Normally it means "the final part of something" (here "something" is the procedure). If this is still the case, then  "the entire body" seems to be familiar with the first part, middle part" of it. Oddly enough, I don't know what they exactly mean.

> But no transplant had ever been performed where **the entire body of an individual is unfamiliar at the conclusion of the procedure**, and one of the few documents discussing the ethics in the biomedical literature, a letter to the editor of a journal published in 2015, foresaw a high risk of insanity as a result of the procedure.

> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_transplant)

Comment: When the procedure has been completed, the patient's entire body will be unfamiliar to them.

Answer (score 1):

It is contrasting head transplants with other types of transplants. With regular transplants only one body part will be different once transplant is completed; with head transplants the entirety of the body (excluding the head) will be different. The point is that with such a significant change the psychological issues will likely be more pronounced than in cases of regular transplants where the change is much less significant.